# How to remove Text area of comment in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hellow there all I tried searching everywhere but I coudn't just find it - may be because its a wiered requirement all I want to do is remove my Comment Text area in wordpress comment - I sucessfully removed URL website and name in the comment field by using following code

```
    <?php
    function remove_comment_fields($fields) {
    unset($fields['url']);
    unset($fields['author']);
    unset($fields['email']);
    return $fields;
    }
    add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','remove_comment_fields');
    ?>
```

But not able to remove the Text area - Actually you all will thought what will I do removing all this I am using a plugin which allow you to post images in your comment and the only option I want to give to user is post images via comment. please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Two options, the `comment_form_defaults` filter:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'so16856397_comment_form_defaults', 10, 1 );
function so16856397_comment_form_defaults( $defaults )
{
    $defaults['comment_field'] = '';
    return $defaults;
}
```

or the `comment_form_field_comment` filter:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_field_comment', 'so16856397_comment_form_field_comment', 10, 1 );
function so16856397_comment_form_field_comment( $field )
{
    return '';
}
```

Check the [`comment_form` source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1509).

Comment: Cheers! If this answer solved your problem, feel free to mark it as the correct answer by checking off the grey check mark under the answer score.

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide the textarea comment box by taking its id set to `display:none` from CSS

Answer (score 0):

Just simple, add this code in functions.php file

```
function disable_comments_everywhere( $open, $post_id ) {
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'comments_open', 'disable_comments_everywhere', 10 , 2 );
```